# Passing data to JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am trying to pass some data (Article object) to JSP but nothing seems to display I am not sure what I did wrong. when clicking the hyperlink which has the article id I want to be able to display the title and the body of the article. I think I must have done something wrong on the doGet method. At the moment I get an empty page when I click the hyperlink to display the article.

```java
public static Article articleById(int id, Connection conn) throws SQLException {
  try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT * FROM myarticles  WHERE artid = ?")) {
    stmt.setInt(1, id);

    try (ResultSet resultset = stmt.executeQuery()) {

      if (resultset.next()) {
        Article article = new Article();
        article.setArtid(resultset.getInt("artid"));
        article.setTitle(resultset.getString("title"));
        article.setBody(resultset.getString("body"));
        return article;

      } else {

        return null;
      }

    }
  }
}
```

```java
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

  try (Connection conn = DBConnectionUtils.getConnectionFromSrcFolder("connection.properties")) {
    Article articleid = ArticleDAO.articleById(id, conn);
    req.setAttribute("articlebyid", articleid);


    req.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/content-page.jsp").forward(req, resp);
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("error " + e.getSQLState());

  }
}
```

upon clicking on the hyperlink which contains the article id I want to display the title and the body of the article

```html
<c:forEach var="articles" items="${article}">
  <tr>
    <td>${articles.artid}</td>
    <td><a href="./article-content?id=${articles.artid}">${articles.title}</a></td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Article title goes here</h1>
  ${articlebyid.title}

  <p>Article body goes here</p>
  ${articlebyid.body}
</div>
```

```html
I forget to include the doget method that display the list of article title that has the hyperlink to display the body and title of the article. here 

@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try (Connection conn = DBConnectionUtils.getConnectionFromSrcFolder("connection.properties")) {

            List<Article> allarticle =ArticleDAO.getAllArticles(conn);
            req.setAttribute("article",allarticle);

            req.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/article-list-page.jsp").forward(req,resp);
        }catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("error "+ e.getSQLState());

        }


    }
```

Comment: `<td>${article.artid}</td>` - should be singular

Comment: `Article articleid = ArticleDAO.articleById(id, conn);` in the `doGet(...)` method - where does the `id` variable come from? IMHO you miss something like `int id = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("id"));`.

Comment: Thanks heaps. I included and it it work.